# How do i do a Does not equal multiple numbers?

Tags: python

i'm using python 3.2.3 idle 
here's my code:

```
number = input("please enter 1 or 2")
if number != 1 or 2: #this part is wrong
     print("You didn't enter 1 or 2")
```

my code is incorrect. i want to make it so that if the user doesn't enter 1 or 2, error pops up. say they enter 1.5, 3, etc or something that isn't 1.0 or 2.0.

how do i do that using the **!=** command?

Comment: It's disturbingly hard to use search to find an exact duplicate, but this is asked at least once a week.

Comment: @Wooble -- That's the name of the game.  Some questions are asked super frequently, but quite difficult to index in a reasonable way for search engines to find apparently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the code is parsed as

```
if ((number != 1) or 2):
```

and `2`, being nonzero, is always True.

Instead I would suggest

```
if number not in (1, 2):
```

Comment: While it will make no real difference, it'd be a good idea to use a set rather than a tuple (set literals are supported from 2.7 up), e.g: `if number not in {1, 2}:` as sets have very fast checks on membership. This might matter if the set is much larger than this simple example.

Comment: I agree in general, but in this case I think it's a distraction from the core issue of a beginner's question.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `in`/`not in`:

```
if number not in (1,2):
```

Don't forget to create an integer out of your number as well...

```
number = int(input("please enter 1 or 2"))
```

Your code as is will never give a `True` result since you're comparing strings to integers (which will always be inequal).

Comment: Note `input` not `raw_input` so `1` is really type `int` not `string`

Comment: @sudo_O -- Incorrect (I didn't notice it at first either).  OP is using python3.2.3 where `input` is the same thing as python2.x's `raw_input` (python3 has got rid of the version with the implicit `eval`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if number!=1 and number!=2
```